# Magic Mouse Clicking Issues

Tags: 12.04, magic-mouse

I am using Apple Magic Mouse on Ubuntu 12.04, it is working well most of the time. However, sometimes what should be a simple left-click triggers some weird behaviors, like pasting the content of the clipboard if I click on editable text area. Or closing the browser tab when I was just selecting the tab.

Does any how to fix those issues or at at least where should I be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

I have just found the answer to this, it thinks there is a middle button, to disable it follow the instructions in this post

[Disabling middle button on Apple Magic Mouse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112454/disabling-middle-button-on-apple-magic-mouse)